# Does vagrant automatically install puppet?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have this in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision "puppet"
  end
```

Yet, when I run `puppet --version` I get :

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ puppet --version
-bash: puppet: command not found
```

Do I need to manually install puppet?

Comment: It depends on the Vagrant Box you are using. Some have Puppet preinstalled. Others, like CentOS, don't.

Comment: There exists an enhancement request asking for this: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10089 -- hopefully it'll happen at some point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, (at the moment) Vagrant doesn't install it automatically.

So you either need to use a basebox which already has it installed (Puppet Labs [provides](http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/) boxes too), or you need to install it yourself. Probably the easiest way to install is to use [shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) before the puppet provisioner(s).

Comment: Ok, I'll use a shell provisioner. I've found a few on github.

Comment: I've just added an example for such a shell provisioner for ubuntu/xenial64 below - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189525/1510754

Comment: Strangely, it does do this automatically with salt and chef... but not puppet, for some reason.

Comment: Oh, but an enhancement request does exist for this: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10089

Answer (score 7):

In response to @tmatilai, I created this simple set up:

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos6.5_64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "manifests/puppet.sh"
  config.vm.provision "puppet"
end
```

manifest/puppet.sh:

```
echo "Adding puppet repo"
sudo rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/puppetlabs-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
echo "installing puppet"
sudo yum install puppet -y
echo "ensure puppet service is running"
sudo puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true
#echo "ensure puppet service is running"
#sudo puppet resource service puppetmaster ensure=running enable=true

echo "ensure puppet service is running for standalone install"
sudo puppet resource cron puppet-apply ensure=present user=root minute=30 command='/usr/bin/puppet apply $(puppet apply --configprint manifest)'
```

---

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 home]$ puppet --version
3.4.2
```

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that this sort of dynamic puppet installation was preferred nowadays.  Any idea if that's correct?

Comment: Fair enough :) Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a plugin, I made one that will automatically install Puppet from a version given in the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.puppet_install.puppet_version = :latest

end
```

This will also do a few cool tricks like make sure the puppet version you specify is a valid version and the like, full details here: https://github.com/petems/vagrant-puppet-install/

Comment: Is there something that prevents this plugin from using anything greater than puppet 3.4.3?

Comment: Nope, it should work with whatever is the latest version of Puppet found on the package provider you use (without a specific version it just runs `apt-get install puppet`, `yum install puppet`, `pkg_add puppet` etc)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I'm not sure what the state of Vagrant was at the time of some of these other answers, but these days puppet does not have to be installed via a shell provisioner, as Vagrant has a support puppet provisioner built right in.

At the most basic level, you can make sure puppet is supported on your box by adding `provision "puppet"` or `provision "puppet_server"` to your `Vagrantfile. For example:

```
#open config block (already present in your templated Vagrantfile)
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  #...[snip]... other config.vm settings. Ex...
  # Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version
  #config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Make puppet avail inside machine
  config.vm.provision "puppet"


#close out Vagrant configuration for this instance
end
```

[using `puppet`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet.html) sets up puppet for local `puppet apply` (uses local manifests for configuring your machine), whereas [using `puppet_server`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_agent.html) hooks you up to a puppet master, and allows you to provision your vagrant box using a puppet server (a puppet master agent).

Comment: The question was how to install Puppet on a Vagrant box which does not have it already installed. As far as I know, Vagrant still doesn't install it automatically (only Chef), so you either have to use a provisioner (or plugin), or a pre-built box.

Comment: This answer is wrong. As @tmatilai said you must install puppet within the vm yourself. See my answer below for the appropriate doc reference.

Comment: You are correct, buy I can't delete an accepted answer unfortunately. I messaged the OP but no luck

Answer (score 4):

As a few other people have already answered, there is no 'standard' that ensures a vagrant box comes pre-installed with Puppet.

By design, a vagrant box could have 'anything' pre-installed on it. Or it could just as easily have 'nothing' at all pre-installed. It all depends on who created it and what they included in the process of setting up the box.

If you find that your machine doesn't have Puppet pre-installed on it, you could also use one of the scripts that [Mitchell Hashimoto](https://github.com/mitchellh) has put together. See the following project on GitHub for details...

https://github.com/hashicorp/puppet-bootstrap

Comment: What's weird to me is that vagrant doesn't install it for you, though.  This wouldn't be weird, except that _it does this for various other provisioners_!  (It does this for at least chef and salt.)  I don't suppose this is the place to request that the folks at HashiCorp change this, just... commenting in case others might be confused by the disparity.

Answer (score 2):

At this point of time of writing, Vagrant does pre-installs puppet service. I ssh-ed into guest machine (used the box 'ubuntu/trusty64') and got following result :

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ puppet --version
3.4.3
```

Comment: As tmatilai said, it depends on where you get the Vagrant box from, some Vagrant boxes have Puppet pre-installed and some don't

Comment: Agreed. In my ubuntu box. it came preconfigured, whereas in my colleague's experiment his centos box probably didnt came with puppet preinstalled

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others it depends on the box. For instance `ubuntu/trusty64` comes with puppet pre-installed whereas `ubuntu/xenial64` does not.

So to fix this for Ubuntu `ubuntu/xenial64` adding an inline shell provisioner before the puppet provisioner is enough:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install puppet'

config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As of June 16 2016 Vagrant does NOT install puppet within the client VM as far as I can tell. I believe like it's sister project "packer" it expects you to do so explicitly. See: https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/puppet-masterless.html

> Note: Puppet will not be installed automatically by this provisioner.
>   This provisioner expects that Puppet is already installed on the
>   machine. It is common practice to use the shell provisioner before the
>   Puppet provisioner to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
this worked for me:
```

> put this inside your Vagrantfile - before your provisioning

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
echo I am installing puppet on guest 
sudo apt-get install -yq puppet=*
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

This should install a puppet agent on the guest before you do other provisioning